# How to check whether IP address is reachable or not using C#

Tags: c#, tcp, server, ip, client-server

I am validating whether the given IP is reachable or not. In server PING, TELNET, etc options are disabled.
I tried with Socket Connection but this needs the given PORT to be allowed.

Is there any reliable solution to check this. It should work on all the environment [independent of OS]

Please guide me to implement this on C#

Comment: If you do not know a port then How you hope to install package? you should have some permissions

Comment: "port needs to be allowed" - well, yeah, that's called security. I wouldn't want some random person remotely installing stuff on my computer without me allowing it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as "IP address is reachable" in general. Relevant is, if a specific service on a server can be successfully contacted - because at the end one wants to use the server for a specific purpose. Checking if one can ping the server says nothing about this: it might be that ping is disabled or blocked but that the server can still be reached by HTTP (i.e. web). Similar it might be that ping works but HTTP will not work either because there is no HTTP service running at the server or because some firewall in between is blocking access to HTTP for all or even only for specific clients.

Thus, you have to decide what you really want to know, i.e. what you want to achieve with the knowledge of the IP being reachable.  For example if you want to use this knowledge to access the web server there later you should try a connection at port 80 (default port for HTTP).

Comment: actually what i want to do is need to install package on fresh remote server, before that i need to check whether that remote server is reachable or not. [Ping, Telnet, etc.. are disabled]. i tried with socket but that needs port to be enabled.

Comment: @saravana: You need to have some service enabled at the server in order to find out if the server is reachable. Given that you want to install a package on a remote server you likely want to do this not by sitting at the server but by logging in from remote. Thus such remote login service (like SSH, port 22) needs to be enabled at the server and you can check if you can reach this service.